# Reading of 第1希望?

Tags: readings, counters

How does one read the phrase 第1希望? Like this, maybe?

> 結婚【けっこん】して子【こ】どもがいる人生【じんせい】が第【だい】[1希望]【いっきぼう】だったから、他【ほか】のことは何【なに】も頑張【がんば】ってきていない

*My first choice was to get married and have children, so I haven't worked hard for anything else.*

It appeared here:

https://otekomachi.yomiuri.co.jp/lifestyle/20211101-OKT8T313225/?utm_source=yomiuri&utm_medium=yol&utm_campaign=yoltop_otekomachi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's いち.

第一希望{だいいちきぼう}, 第二希望{だいにきぼう}, 第三希望{だいさんきぼう}.

---

FYI 第N志望{しぼう} means the same thing.

Comment: Thanks! With no native speakers around to ask, I often have trouble finding answers to what could be simple questions.